# Stream a local mp3 file to a remote UPnP-client without a UPnP-server

Tags: remote, streaming, dlna, upnp

I have a nice hardware UPnP streaming client (Phillips NP2900) here in my room.

I want to play music from my PC (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS) on that remote device. But I don't want to setup a complete UPnP-server on my PC for that.

Please remember the Windows Media Player. It recognize any UPnP/DLNA-client in available it offer to play on it. This worked fine on windows. I need something like that on a unixoid system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest http://www.eezupnp.de/ - simple nice and easy. Supports playlists. Plays files directly from a hard disk. I use it all the time.